# su: Authentication failure

Tags: ubuntu, pam, su

I have `Ubuntu 14.04` server on which I can't use anything that relies on `su`. This manifests in inability to restart services or even switch users.

```
root@ci-web1:~# su - mxx
su: Authentication failure
```

My `/var/log/auth.log` shows:

```
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_rootok.so): /lib/security/pam_rootok.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_rootok.so
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_unix.so): /lib/security/pam_unix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_unix.so
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: FAILED su for mxx by root
Oct 10 11:14:15 ci-web1 su[19709]: - /dev/pts/0 root:mxx
```

Both of those files are present in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/`. I don't understand why it's looking in `/lib/security/`.

How to correct this problem?

Comment: Take a look on `/etc/pam.d`, maybe the libs are being refered there.

Comment: @ThoriumBR, unfortunately there are no references to that path anywhere in `/etc/pam.d/`.
Question for others: why are there 2 votes to close this question?

Comment: @Mxx: Probably because it fits better at unix.stackexchange.com. Close includes move votes.

Comment: You can work around it by creating soft links for the required files under /lib/security or, if /lib/security doesn't exist, soft link the directory.

Comment: @Andy creating symlinks didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging through *strace* output and trial and error, the culprit was found. At some point during package updates a dependency link broke between the `login` package and the `libpcre3` module. After reinstalling that specific module to restore the dependency link `su` is now working again.

Comment: Thanks!!! this worked for me: "apt-get install libpcre3 login", packages updated and problems gone! ;-)

Comment: A little bit more information on this using `LD_DEBUG=all su`:
```
libselinux.so.1: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: pcre_free_study (fatal)
file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_rootok.so [0];  destroying link map
...
```

Comment: @azat I don't understand. Are you asking something?

Comment: @Mxx, no, just adding a little note for this issue.